# OLDB to read CSV file but it changes values

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, dataset

I have a OLDB connection to read a csv file into a dataset. Now in the CSV I have a column like 3,00 or 15,00 (it's an amount in euro's) but when I call the .Fill method of the OdbcDataAdapter it changes the value into a DateTime. This is the code I use to read the CSV and convert it to a dataset:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                // Creates and opens an ODBC connection
                string strConnString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + filePath.Trim() + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False";
                string sql_select;
                OdbcConnection conn;
                conn = new OdbcConnection(strConnString.Trim());
                conn.Open();

                //Creates the select command text
                sql_select = "select * from [" + this.fileName.Trim() + "]";

                //Creates the data adapter
                OdbcDataAdapter obj_oledb_da = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql_select, conn);

                //Fills dataset with the records from CSV file
                obj_oledb_da.Fill(ds, "csv");

                //closes the connection
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) //Error
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error - LoadCSV", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            return ds;
```

A record of the CSV looks like this:

```
2005    2   20  7024    0   0   2900    14  19  0,00    3,00    3,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    15,80   18,80   0,00    0,00    90014   99999998    99999998        0   0   23/02/2005  0   stt     7024    15,80   0,00    N   60376940043 fis
```

The record received from the dataset looks like this:

```
2005    2   20  7024    0   0   2900    14  19  30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 15:26:00 30-12-1899 15:26:00 30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00  80,33   95,59   30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00  92705   99999998    99999998        0   0   23-2-2005 0:00:00   0   stt     7024    80,33   30-12-1899 0:00:00  N       fis
```

What am I missing here? Because the record of the DataSet should be exactly the same as the CSV record. I need to convert the CSV to a DataSet because I don't want to add every seperate line into the database, so I insert the DataSet at once into the database (it's an import module)

Who can help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I missing something - is your file comma separated or tab separated?  Is it a comma separated file with comma as the decimal point?  That could cause some issues.  Could you post the exact format of the line in the file?

Comment: maybe you need the commas in code to be replace by `.`, now it's interpreted as time. that my humble opinion.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned it, but it's tab separated... It is possible to quickly replace the ',' by a '.' in the code or do I have to replace it with notepad++ or something?

Comment: What is 'OLDB'? Do you perhaps mean ODBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a schema.ini file if you really want to use the text driver to import the records.  I think it imports the date time according to your region settings in control panel:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx

This was linked to from this page:

http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2009/04/parse-csv-files-with-ms-odbc-driver.html

You should also consider parsing the file manually, which will give you more control over how to interpret the date field.

Comment: First of all thank you for you answer. Parsing the file manually takes a lot of time. I now import 170k records in 10 seconds. If I do it manually, it takes over 10 minutes which is too long for our customer...

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't added the columns to the schema.ini Once added, and adjusted the field types it worked like a charm...